# Returning not empty relation table, after applying filter

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am applying filter on the relation table. And I try to return relation only has data.

```
$price = 900000;

$places = Place::with(["plans" => function($query){
      $query->orderBy("plan_price");
}, "basicInfos", "albums"])
->when($price, function($query) use ($price){
      $query->with(["plans" => function($query) use ($price){
            return $query->where("plan_price", "<=", $price);
        }]);
})
->whereHas("plans")
->get()
->groupBy("place_name")
->toArray();
```

When I do it like above. It's filters the relation table which is `plans`. So some `plans` are empty. Because of the `$price` and I don't want those `places`. For that I use `->whereHas("plans")` But it's still returning `places` with empty `plans`

[image]

I tried to use `->has("plans)` as well. But the results didn't changed. Am I doing wrong, is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it. But not sure it's right way.

After this:

```
->groupBy("place_name")->toArray();
```

I check the relation table with below.

```
foreach ($places as $place) {
    foreach ($place as $val) {
        if (!empty($val["plans"])) {
            $placesArray[] = $place;
        }
    }
}
```

I am open to another options about this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your query is that you are trying to filter the main query 
 by applying the filter in subquery or relationship using `when()` but you should actually use `whereHas()` to filter the main query.

Try:

```
$places = Place::with(["plans" => function ($query) {
        $query->orderBy("plan_price");
    }, "basicInfos", "albums"])
        ->whereHas('plans', function ($query) use ($price) {
            return $query->where("plan_price", "<=", $price);
        })
        ->get()
        ->groupBy("place_name")
        ->toArray();
```

Comment: I tried your advice and having an error `Illegal operator and value combination.
`

Comment: are you using the same query? And make sure that $price is not null.

Comment: also, I just checked `groupBy()` after the `get()` method will not work as expected.